Android Studio cannot debug. It never starts to run
I have a Dart server (no Flutter) and I am using Android Studio. When I run it, it runs without problems, but it does not start the debugging process at all. I debugged with prints and it does not run print the first line of main, so the process is not starting at all. I cannot find any debug configuration.
This is the debug Window when I click the debug button:

As you can see I can't resume, so it means it's not paused. I also cannot use the pause button.
This is the Run window when I click the run button:

If I try to attach the debugger to process, I get this:

This is the main:
void main() async {
  print('Running');
  await DatabaseManager.connect();
  Server.init();
}

I don't know if it has something to do with--pause_isolates_on_start. It's not set in any configuration so I don't know where that flag is coming from.
Also I have the Dart SDK from Flutter but I am not using Flutter in this project. I don't know if that can be related.
EDIT: the project debugs in Visual Studio Code but not in Android Studio.
I tried running it through terminal with dart --observe main.dart and connect to dev tools. This is the output:
PS D:\Sources\thesis\lib> dart --observe main.dart         
Running
vm-service: isolate (4091118387) 'main' has no debugger attached and is paused due to exception.  Connect to the Dart VM service at http:/.. to debug.
vm-service: isolate (4091118387) 'main' has no debugger attached and is paused due to exception.  Connect to the Dart VM service at http:/.. to debug.
vm-service: isolate (4091118387) 'main' has no debugger attached and is paused due to exception.  Connect to the Dart VM service at http:/.. to debug.

Notice how the "Running" print and the beginning of the main does appear this time.
